# Why is there "markov property" in proving the renewal equation for a renewal process?

Tags: stochastic-processes

When proving the renewal equation for a renewal process in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renewal_theory#The_renewal_equation)

> The renewal function satisfies
>   $$
>     m(t) = F_S(t) + \int_0^t m(t-s) f_S(s)\, ds 
> $$
>   where $F_S$ is the cumulative distribution function of $S_1$ and $f_S$ is the corresponding probability density function.
>
> **Proof of the renewal equation**
>
> We may iterate the expectation about the first holding time:
>   $$
>         m(t) = \mathbb{E}[X_t] = \mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(X_t \mid S_1)]. \, 
> $$
>       But by *the Markov property*
>   $$
>         \mathbb{E}(X_t \mid S_1=s) = \mathbb{I}_{\{t \geq s\}} \left( 1 + \mathbb{E}[X_{t-s}] \right). \, 
> $$
>   ...

A renewal process is not Markovian. Why is there "by the Markov property" in the proof? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The renewal process $(X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$ is not a Markov *process* but it satisfies the Markov *property* at time $S_1$. That is, for every $s$, the process $(X_{t+s})_{t\geqslant0}$ conditioned by the event $[S_1=s]$ is distributed like the process $(1+X_t)_{t\geqslant0}$.